# google maps android api v2 using supportmapfragment

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I tried to install project present in [tutorial](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/google-maps-in-android-application-with-new-google-maps-android-api-v2-using-supportmapfragment/):

All It's ok but when run project, logcat say:

"Could not find class 'maps.ag.l', referenced from method maps.ah.an.a"

The map is empty and logcat say:

" Failed to load map. Error contacting Google servers. This is probably an authentication issue (but could be due to network errors).

I have changed package name from "in.wptrafficanalyzer.locationgooglemapv2demo"  to "it.appatwork" and i have got the apikey for android maps apiV2 with my sha1.

I have android 2.3.3

Please help me!

Mainactivity:

`package it.appatwork.locationgooglemapv2demo;`

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.Menu;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable (getApplicationContext());
    if(status == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
        System.out.println("ok");
    }

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:id="@+id/map"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

AndoridManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="it.appatwork.locationgooglemapv2demo"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

<permission
      android:name="it.appatwork.locationgooglemapv2demo.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
      android:protectionLevel="signature"/>

<uses-permission android:name="it.appatwork.locationgooglemapv2demo.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>


<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="it.appatwork.locationgooglemapv2demo.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>


    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyBgkEwv0Z4O2t27avrve_33N33QY0wHNXg"/>        

</application>

</manifest>
```

**UPDATE:**

this is the logcat output:

`07-24 23:11:40.849: W/dalvikvm(6472): VFY: unable to resolve instance field 24`
`07-24 23:11:41.149: W/dalvikvm(6472): Unable to resolve superclass of Lmaps/p/w; (718)`
`07-24 23:11:41.149: W/dalvikvm(6472): Link of class 'Lmaps/p/w;' failed`
`07-24 23:11:41.149: W/dalvikvm(6472): Unable to resolve superclass of Lmaps/aq/as; (5347)`
`07-24 23:11:41.149: W/dalvikvm(6472): Link of class 'Lmaps/aq/as;' failed`
`07-24 23:11:41.149: W/dalvikvm(6472): Unable to resolve superclass of Lmaps/ag/l; (4576)`
`07-24 23:11:41.149: W/dalvikvm(6472): Link of class 'Lmaps/ag/l;' failed`
`07-24 23:11:41.149: E/dalvikvm(6472): Could not find class 'maps.ag.l', referenced from method maps.ah.an.a`
    `07-24 23:11:41.149: W/dalvikvm(6472): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 4420          (Lmaps/ag/l;) in Lmaps/ah/an;`
    `07-24 23:11:41.359: I/ApplicationPackageManager(6472): cscCountry is not German : WIN`
    `07-24 23:11:47.069: W/Google Maps Android API(6472): Please add <uses-permission      android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/> into AndroidManifest.xml to ensure  correct behavior under poor connectivity conditions.`
    `07-24 23:11:47.069: I/Google Maps Android API(6472): Failed to contact Google servers. Another attempt will be made when connectivity is established.
07-24 23:11:59.009: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(6472): getExtractedText on inactive InputConnection
07-24 23:11:59.009: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(6472): getExtractedText on inactive InputConnection
07-24 23:12:02.289: E/Google Maps Android API(6472): Failed to load map. Error contacting Google servers. This is probably an authentication issue (but could be due to network errors).`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all the two problem you are describing are not related one to another, you main problem is here:

> Failed to load map. Error contacting Google servers. This is probably
>   an authentication issue (but could be due to network errors).

This means that you have some kind of problem with you permissions in the manifest file, or with you configuration in the Google API's console.

Please go over all the steps of this two blog post, [Google Maps API V2 key](http://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=403) and [Google Maps API V2](http://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=435), and commit all the steps, if you still have problems post here your code and updated logcat message.

**UPDATE:**

You package name:

```
package="it.appatwork.locationgooglemapv2demo"
```

does not match the package name you specified in the permissions:

```
permission
      android:name="it.appatwork.LocationGoogleMapV2Demo.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
      android:protectionLevel="signature"/>

<uses-permission android:name="it.appatwork.LocationGoogleMapV2Demo.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
```

I think it's case-sensitive so try to change it to:

```
permission
      android:name="it.appatwork.locationgooglemapv2demo.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
      android:protectionLevel="signature"/>

<uses-permission android:name="it.appatwork.locationgooglemapv2demo.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
```

Comment: Thank's emil, but I have read it yet...I have read lot of tutorial and post about this topic, followed tips, but nothing, don't work...always the same messages

Comment: I have changed AndroidManifest (I have posted new version), but the output of logcat doesn't change...

Comment: @DavideDiFilippo:i have the same issue,i'm tryin to solve it.wen i solve i post the solution here.let inform me wen u solved..

Comment: IT WORKS!!! :) I have changed it.appatwork.locationgooglemapv2demo -> it.appatwork.lgv2 everywhere, and i have changed the name of app from mainactivity ->  lgv2....And I have added in layout file xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" in the map fragment.....

Comment: So after making the suggested edits the maps started to work?

Comment: could you please go over this blog post, and make sure you did all the step of configuring the API Console correctly: http://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=403

Comment: So why are you saying that it doesn't works if you wrote "IT WORKS"?